# why am i not able to reuse InputStream?

Tags: java

```
public static String getTextOf(String xsl) throws Exception {
      DocXHandler docxh1 = new DocXHandler(ACE.getInputFilePath());
      InputStream inputDocumentXMLStream = docxh1.getInputDocumentXMLZERO();
    return new Cache().getXSLOutput(inputDocumentXMLStream, xsl);
}
```

The above method will be called more than 100 times with different xsl arguments. Now each time InputStream inputDocumentXMLStream has been assigned value( yeah more than 100 times). As i am trying to refactor this code, in such a way that only one time InputStream will be assigned value.My code became like this now,

```
  public static String getTextOf(String xsl) throws Exception {
     return new Cache().getXSLOutput(inputDocumentXMLStream, xsl);
   }
```

by changing inputDocumentXMLStream as global property. First time i am getting the correct result BUT for the second time i get the below error,

```
Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

so tel me how to read it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't restart reading the input stream after reach to the end of the steam** as it moves in single direction only.

I think the best idea to solve your problem is to fully parse your XML file once and place the values in the some java objects. Once done, you can simply use the map to to retrieve the required values. **This will be much efficient too.**

e.g.

```
    Object parseValueMap = paseXML(inputDocumentXMLStream);//use appropriate object
    //^ called only once, you may use some libraries such as JAXB to parse the xml
```

Assuming `xsl` is a path expression, you may want to apply the path on Java collection created in above step. You may use libraries such as `JXPath` as :

```
     String value = JXPathEvaluator(parseValueMap, xsl);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Kate: It should be helpful. I understand, its little extra effort in programming as compared to reading the same file again and again. But once done, I think it's much better.

Comment: @Kate the advice is not to save the `InputStream` in the `Map` (which is a really bad approach). You should open the file (with the `InputStream` or other), parse the file to build an in-memory representation of the file and have methods to facilitate access and navigation through this structure.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I already mentioned, I am not advising to use any specific java object. I am trying to share the idea of parsing the file once and reusing the parsed objects. Nothing else. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: She asked (in the deleted comment) if it would be a good idea to store the `InputStream` inside a `Map`, I just tried to guide her by first saying that would be a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry guys to delete the comment. It happened accidently.

Comment: @YogendraSingh - I copied my XMl file in a static String and converted it to Stream for each method invocation. It works. I have done this based upon your guidance. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

You can only read a stream once, then you are at EOF, as the error message says. What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are doing in `getXSLOutput` and why you need to read the same inputstream 100 times however to avoid EOF you can use [mark(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark%28int%29) to mark the start of the stream in your`getXSLOutput` method and call [reset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) at the end of the same method. Seems like the wrong thing to do though...

For better results try reading it once and storing the contents in a datatype inJava then working on that 100 times.

Comment: @
ramsinb - I tried with mark(0) and reset() and got 'java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported'.

Comment: That suggests that the implementation of `InputStream` returned by `DocXHandler.getInputDocumentXMLZERO` doesn't not implement the `mark` or `reset` methods therefore this approach won't work. You should look at alternative of populating a Java data structure and using that in your 100 method invocations.

Comment: @ramsinb- Thanks for the comment, i was relying on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse an input stream across file with out closing it. All file I/O functions rely on EOF to stop.

Answer (score 0):

for each xls file you have to parse the file and create a Excel Document instance of Java.
That Java instance will give you InputStream. So there is no escape for you in this case.

But for the same file you can use the same InputStream. And that would be a single unit or work.